# 投稿時の書式設定に関するヘルプページにコードフェンスの説明を追記したい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  におけるコードブロックの説明で、[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ではコードフェンスの記述が追加されているので、日本語版でも追従する形で追記したいです。

> Alternatively, you can use fenced code blocks instead of indenting your code samples. Wrap your code in three or more backtick (```` ``` ````) or tilde (`~~~`) characters:
>
> ````
> ```
> console.log("Hello, World");
> ```
> ````

Answer (score 0):

以下の通り、[以前に](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3603/4) nekketsuuu さんが翻訳くださっていたものを、ヘルプに反映いたしました。

---

> スペース4つの代わりに、特定の記号でコードを囲うことでも整形ができます。コードの最初と最後に3つ以上のバッククォート (```` ``` ````) かチルダ (`~~~`) を入れてください：
>
> ````
> ```
> console.log("Hello, World");
> ```
> ````